# got error on xcode7. view.layer.renderInContext(context!)

Tags: swift, xcode7

The error said that "Value of optional type 'CGContext?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?".

Does anyone know how to fix this??

```
       view.layer.renderInContext(context!)
```

Answer (score 0):

If that line is giving you that error, `context` had to be of type `CGContext??`.

You can, as the error says, use `!` or `?` to unwrap the optional resulting from the expression `context!`.